# Whether is it possible to indicate the printer to next page?

Tags: printing

I am using php language.  I project i have the application to be print,  It contain two pages.  According to the data available the page content may be change, so printout of first page end and second page starting content not to be proper.

So i want to know any other way is there, to separate the specific content to be printed from the second page ?

Comment: How are you sending the data to the printer?

Comment: @ ignacio, from php page coding as a separate page which as html view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied all the css method, but not get proper solution.  I manually calculated and left the space for this depending on the condition.  So i solve this problem with correct result.

Thanks for everyone those who guide and answer for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are the [CSS page break properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-breaks).  The w3schools.com site has [usage guidelines](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_print_pageba.asp) for the commonly used `page-break-after` property.